# camera_info override

Tags: ros, camera-info, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I've been using an android app to pipe the camera image into ROS.

This works moderately well, even though there is some lag to get the image.

The problem is that the published /camera/camera_info is all empty. (see below)

Is there a way I can override the camera_info topic with the calibration data I've gathered, and bypass what the AndroidCameraViewer driver reports ?

Thank you

Output of :

```
$ rostopic echo /camera/camera_info 

header: 
  seq: 7485
  stamp: 
    secs: 1412290798
    nsecs: 453000000
  frame_id: camera
height: 960
width: 1280
distortion_model: ''
D: []
K: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
R: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
P: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi: 
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: False
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194091/camera_info-override/) by [mtourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/7136/mtourne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to run CameraCalibrator.py, obtain a calibration .yaml file from that script, then provide your image publisher the URL to your calibration yaml file as a parameter to the image publisher.

[This page](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) gives details on the calibration process.

What are you using to publish these images? Does it have a camera_info_url parameter, or anything like that?

---

Originally posted by [TimboInSpace](https://answers.ros.org/users/11216/timboinspace/) with karma: 141 on 2014-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mtourne](https://answers.ros.org/users/7136/mtourne/) on 2014-12-15**:
I've been using an android app (which doesn't appear to be on the store anymore), basically it was missing some information in the topics published that prevented other nodes that would consume camera data to function properly. I was curious if I could manually fake this data.

**Comment by [TimboInSpace](https://answers.ros.org/users/11216/timboinspace/) on 2014-12-18**:
You don't need to fake it. One option is: on the non-android device set up a camera info manager publishing on a different camera name than your current one. Then set up an mage_transport republisher on the same name as your new camera info manager. Hope it goes well